# Print lines between two patterns along with the header

Tags: awk, sed

I have the file like this below:

```
Name: DB1
========================================================
Primary :
f3
f6
f7
f9
f0
Secondary :
internal input
internal output
internal Loaded
internal output
internal Loaded

Name: DB2
========================================================
Primary :
s2
m5
m7
m8
m9 
Secondary :
External output
External Revoke
External Reuse
External input
```

But I need the output like this need to extract the lines between Primary and Secondary along with the names:

```
Name: DB1
========================================================
f3
f6
f7
f9
f0

Name: DB2
========================================================
Primary :
s2
m5
m7
m8
```

I tried this :

```
$ awk '/Primary :/{flag=1; next} /Undriven :/{flag=0} flag' file
f3
f6
f7
f9
f0
s2
m5
m7
m8
m9
```

I am not getting the names can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: The string `Undriven :` doesn't appear in your input so that may be an issue for you. I assume the first `Primary` and `m9` being missing from the expected output is a mistake. If so please fix it, if not then please explain the criteria to omit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're pretty close, except that (a) you're never explicitly matching the `Name:` line, and (b) you're matching the word "Undriven" which doesn't appear in your sample data.

I would probably do something like this:

```
awk '
/^Name:/
/^====/
/^Primary :/{flag=1; next}
/^Secondary :/{flag=0}
flag
' file
```

Which produces as output:

```
Name: DB1
========================================================
f3
f6
f7
f9
f0
Name: DB2
========================================================
s2
m5
m7
m8
m9
```

Comment: Naming a flag variable `flag` is like naming a numeric variable `number` instead of `count` or `sum` or `total` or `average` or whatever it represents - it's a missed opportunity to provide some useful information on what the code does. In this case `found` (often abbreviated to just `f`) is the common name for the flag variable that you set when you found something in the input. If you just swap the order of the 2 comparisons that set/clear the flag and put the test that's causing the print in between them (`/Sec/{f=0} f; /Prim/{f=1}`) then you don't need a `next`.

Comment: I agree in general, although my opinion on this matter isn't as strong as yours. In general my policy is to reuse as much of the OP's code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output that this doesn't work for:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{for (i=1;i<=8;i++) print $i; print ""}' file
Name: DB1
========================================================
Primary :
f3
f6
f7
f9
f0

Name: DB2
========================================================
Primary :
s2
m5
m7
m8
m9
```

or:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '{print $1 ORS $2; for (i=4;i<=8;i++) print $i; print ""}' file
Name: DB1
========================================================
f3
f6
f7
f9
f0

Name: DB2
========================================================
s2
m5
m7
m8
m9
```